# Where should I begin 2d gaming in android studio?

Tags: android, 2d

I hope everyone is good. I am an android fanatic. I have learned almost all android basics. I am quite familiar with the android basics. I have done a lot of small android projects, but have no experience with an android database yet. Now, I want to learn android 2 D gaming. I want to know where to start? What are the requirements to build the platform for that? Could anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm from Portugal and i bought this book: http://www.revista-programar.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/introducao-desenvolvimento-jogos-android.jpeg
It's a really good video, explains everything and gives examples.

I can't find this book in english :( but you can search for one in the internet :D

You can read this post :) they talk about a really good book https://www.quora.com/Which-books-are-the-best-for-Android-game-development

But i never read it so i can't tell you my personal opinion :(

Comment: thanks man. i would check it.

Answer (score 1):

I begin to learn android game development by reading the book [Android Game Programming For Dummies](https://books.google.com.my/books?id=ZgNFCn2iv-AC&printsec=frontcover&dq=introduction%20to%20make%20android%20games&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=introduction%20to%20make%20android%20games&f=false)

I found this book in my university's library and I love this book because it very beginner friendly. You can learn some of the basic concepts on how to build an android game by reading this book. But if you want to make a real android game, knowing how to code is totally not enough. You got to learn some graphical design stuff as no one want to play a game with a very ugly-looking design right? Anyway this is just my personal opinion and hope you can come out with your first android game soon :)

Comment: this seems quite helpful. but i would check it later as i am busy with the navigation at the moment.